# Using arrays in for loops python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to run all the elements in `just_test_data` to all the elements in `just_train_data`, and return the lowest number, then run the new `just_test_data` through all the `just_train_data`, and so on until all the `just_test_data` has been run.

The error I keep getting is in the line

```
step_1 = (abs(just_test_data[i] - just_train_data[n]) ** 2)

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

When I first try to run the loop.

```
import numpy as np
testing_data = np.genfromtxt("C:\Users\zkrumlinde\Desktop\Statistical Programming\Week 3\iris-testing-data.csv", delimiter= ',')
training_data = np.genfromtxt("C:\Users\zkrumlinde\Desktop\Statistical Programming\Week 3\iris-training-data.csv", delimiter= ',')

#create 4 arrays, the first two with the measurements of training and testing data
#the last two have the labels of each line
just_test_data = np.array(testing_data[:, 0:4])
just_train_data = np.array(training_data[:, 0:4])
testing_labels = np.array(testing_data[:, 4])
training_labels = np.array(training_data[:, 4])

n = 0
while n < len(just_train_data):
    for i in just_test_data:
        old_distance = 'inf'
        step_1 = (abs(just_test_data[i] - just_train_data[n]) ** 2)
        step_2 = sum(step_1)
        new_distance = np.sqrt(step_2)
        if new_distance < old_distance:
            old_distance = new_distance
            index = n
        n = n + 1
print(training_labels[index])
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback so we can see what line throws the error rather than digging through code for it.

Comment: Where is the error? Please post a stack trace. What does it mean to "run" all the elements?

Comment: 14     for i in just_test_data:
     15         old_distance = 'inf'
---> 16         step_1 = (abs(just_test_data[i] - just_train_data[n]) ** 2)
     17         step_2 = sum(step_1)
     18         new_distance = np.sqrt(step_2)
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Comment: I'm trying to edit, says my indents are wrong

Comment: In "step_1 = (abs(just_test_data[i] - just_train_data[n]) ** 2)", what happens if you replace "just_test_data[i]"  with "i"? Also, unless you're dealing with complex numbers, taking the absolute value and squaring is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

when you say `for i in just_test_data:` i will be the element itself, not the index.

you probably want something like `for i in range(len(just_test_data))` this will have `i` as a number from `0` to the length of `just_test_data - 1`.

edit: a few weird things in your code:

```
step_1 = (abs(just_test_data[i] - just_train_data[n]) ** 2)
step_2 = sum(step_1)
new_distance = np.sqrt(step_2)
```

this just returns `abs(just_test_data[i] - just_train_data[n])`. are you meaning to add a ton of `step_1` up and then eventually take the `sqrt`? you need to check your indents.

`old_distance = 'inf'` is a string (pretty sure). you are probably looking for either `np.inf` or `float('inf')`. Also because you set this inside the for loop, it is getting reset for every `i`. you probably want it above 'for i in just_test_data:'

a quick pass at your code:

```
min_distance = np.inf
for n in range(len(just_train_data)):
    step_2 = 0
    for i in range(len(just_test_data)):
        step_1 = (just_test_data[i] - just_train_data[n]) ** 2
        step_2 += step_1
    distance = np.sqrt(step_2)
    if distance < min_distance:
        min_distance = distance
        index = n
print(training_labels[index])
```

This compares a point in `just_train_data` to all the points in `just_test_data` to compute a distance. It will print the minimum of these distances.

Answer (score 1):

By using `for i in just_test_data` you're iterating through all the elements in the *just_test_data* array and not and index between 0 and the array length.

Also, it seems that your `n = n + 1` line is not indented correctly.

Here's my guess for an updated version of your code:

```
import numpy as np
testing_data = np.genfromtxt("C:\Users\zkrumlinde\Desktop\Statistical Programming\Week 3\iris-testing-data.csv", delimiter= ',')
training_data = np.genfromtxt("C:\Users\zkrumlinde\Desktop\Statistical Programming\Week 3\iris-training-data.csv", delimiter= ',')

#create 4 arrays, the first two with the measurements of training and testing data
#the last two have the labels of each line
just_test_data = np.array(testing_data[:, 0:4])
just_train_data = np.array(training_data[:, 0:4])
testing_labels = np.array(testing_data[:, 4])
training_labels = np.array(training_data[:, 4])

n = 0
while n < len(just_train_data):
    for i in range(len(just_test_data)):
        old_distance = 'inf'
        step_1 = (abs(just_test_data[i] - just_train_data[n]) ** 2)
        step_2 = sum(step_1)
        new_distance = np.sqrt(step_2)
        if new_distance < old_distance:
            old_distance = new_distance
            index = n
    n = n + 1
print(training_labels[index])
```